# Formatting a Json for Highchart

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, highcharts, format

How can we format the below json format to convert into the required format to use in Highchart. Need to convert the heirarchical json to flat json having proper filter values(categories). Series value is to be use to show the sub-bar graphs inside the main bar(Catgories)
Please refer the below link which i am trying to get from the below json.

https://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-basic

Json to Convert(Available):

```
{
    "SalesValue": {
       "barValue":[{
        "type" :"Maruti",
        "Drills": [
            {"region":"Asia", "value":4},
            {"region":"Australia", "value":87},
            {"region":"America", "value":12}
        ]
      },{
        "type" :"Hyundai",
        "Drills": [
            {"region":"Asia", "value":33},
            {"region":"Australia", "value":5}
        ]
      },{
        "type" :"Toyota",
        "Drills": [
            {"region":"America", "value":33}
        ]
      }]
    }

}
```

Desired Json(to be made):

```
{
    "Chart Value": {
       "Categories":[{
        "name" :["Maruti","Hyundai","Toyota"]
      }],
      "Series":[{
        "name":"Asia",
        "data":[4,33]
      },{
        "name":"Australia",
        "data":[87, 5]
      },{
        "name":"America",
        "data":[12 , 33]
      }]
    }

}
```

Comment: What did you try already? This website is not for others to write code for you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and update your question.

Comment: Please describe more precisely what effect do you want to achieve, or privide us with any mock-up graphic of how your chart should looks like, because I'm a a bit confused about how the drilldowns should be defined there. Actually your "desired JSON" will not work at all.